# Unix generic subprocess error detection

Tags: c++, linux, unix, process

My program (C++) needs to be able to create and destroy many separate subprocesses from user-inputted commands on Unix systems. The subprocesses communicate with my program via pipes and are designed to time out if they don't respond within a certain amount of time. As we will be running the program on Linux servers potentially costing many thousands of dollars, if a process errors or exits we'd like to stop waiting for it and ensure that it's dead rather than waiting for it to time out (which can be on the order of minutes and is consequently valuable server time) and then killing it.

The below code runs perfectly fine when run with straight compiled executables ("cd path/to/directory; ./program"), stopping programs which fail and leaving programs that are still running until they time out, but when given either python or java programs to run (in the form of "cd path/to/file; python3 program.py" or "cd path/to/directory; java program") concludes the subprocess has exited or failed regardless of its actual state. How do I fix this?

--- Create a subprocess ---

```
void Networking::startAndConnectBot(std::string command) {
pid_t pid = (pid_t)NULL;
int writePipe[2];
int readPipe[2];

if(pipe(writePipe) || pipe(readPipe)) {
    throw 1;
}

//Fork a child process
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) { //This is the child
    setpgid(getpid(), getpid());

    dup2(writePipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);

    dup2(readPipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(readPipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);

    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command.c_str(), (char*) NULL);

    //Nothing past the execl should be run

    exit(1);
} else if(pid < 0) {
    if(!quiet_output) std::cout << "Fork failed\n";
    throw 1;
}

UniConnection connection;
connection.read = readPipe[0];
connection.write = writePipe[1];

connections.push_back(connection);
processes.push_back(pid);
```

--- Get a response from a subprocess ---

```
std::string Networking::getString(unsigned char playerTag, unsigned int timeoutMillis) {

std::string newString;

UniConnection connection = connections[playerTag - 1];

fd_set set;
FD_ZERO(&set); /* clear the set */
FD_SET(connection.read, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */

struct timeval timeout; //We want it to be non-blocking, so we'll check every ten millisecond to get a result.
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

char buffer;

//The time we started at.
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point initialTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

//Keep reading char by char until a newline
bool shouldContinue = true;
while(shouldContinue) {
    //Check if process is dead.
    int status;
    if(waitpid(processes[playerTag - 1], &status, WNOHANG) == processes[playerTag - 1] ||
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - initialTime).count() >= timeoutMillis) {
        killPlayer(playerTag);
        if(!quiet_output) {
            // Buffer error message output
            // If a bunch of bots fail at onces, we dont want to be writing to cout at the same time
            // That looks really weird
            std::string errorMessage = "";
            errorMessage += std::string("Unix bot timed out or errored.\n");

            playerLogs[playerTag-1].push_back(newString);
            errorMessage += "#---------ALL OF THE OUTPUT OF THE BOT THAT TIMED OUT----------#\n";
            for(auto stringIter = playerLogs[playerTag-1].begin(); stringIter != playerLogs[playerTag-1].end(); stringIter++) {
                while(stringIter->size() < 60) stringIter->push_back(' ');
                errorMessage += "# " + *stringIter + " #\n";
            }
            errorMessage += "#--------------------------------------------------------------#\n";

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(coutMutex);
            std::cout << errorMessage;
        }
        throw 1;
    }

    //Check if there are bytes in the pipe
    for(int selectionResult = select(connection.read+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout); selectionResult > 0; selectionResult--) {
        read(connection.read, &buffer, 1);

        if(buffer == '\n') {
            shouldContinue = false;
            break;
        }
        else newString += buffer;
    }

    //Reset timeout - we should consider it to be undefined.
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 10000;
}
```

That is to say, whenever the aforementioned java or python commands are run with the program, 1 is thrown from getString regardless of whether or not they actually did exit or error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.